# STL priority_queue using reinsertion for key decrease not working

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I'm trying to implement an A*-like algorithm, and I am having trouble implementing key decrease using the STL `priority_queue` container. I am trying to reinsert elements into the queue when I decrease the key, but they are still not getting popped before elements with higher key.

Here is the main A*-like loop with irrelevant details removed:

```
while (!(open.empty() || (goalExp && switchToEA(firstTimeGoal, reopen)) )) {
        Node *nextParent = open.top();
        open.pop(); // Where the node gets popped
        if (closed.find(nextParent) != closed.end())
            continue;
        closed.insert(nextParent);
        nextParent->expand((*graph)[nextParent->getState()]);
        
        for (auto &i: nextParent->getAdjacent()) {
            T state = i.first;
            cost_t edgeCost = i.second;
            Node *child;
            if (state_to_node.find(state) != state_to_node.end()) {
                child = state_to_node[state];

                if (nextParent->getGCost() + edgeCost < child->getGCost()) {
                    child->setGCost(nextParent->getGCost() + edgeCost);
                    child->setFCost(child->getGCost() + (*h)(state));
                    child->setBack(nextParent);
                    open.push(child); // Key decrease
                } 
            } else {
                child = new Node(nextParent->getGCost() + edgeCost, nextParent->getGCost() + edgeCost + (*h)(state),
                                 state, nextParent);
                open.push(child); // New node insertion
                state_to_node[state] = child;
            }
        }
}
```

Priority queue definition:

```cpp
std::priority_queue<Node *, std::vector<Node *>, typename Node::Compare> open;
```

Comparator class:

```cpp
class Compare {
    public:
        bool operator() (BaseNode * a,BaseNode * b) {
            return a->fcost > b->fcost;
        }

        bool operator() (const BaseNode& a, const BaseNode& b) {
            return a.fcost > b.fcost;
        }
};
```

Comment: You should post a [mcve] with just minimal classes that do not have to do really anything or close to not doing anything, and then a very small piece of code demonstrating the problem using a hard-coded example or two.  I doubt any of the issues have to do with `A*`, so all of the things you are showing us other than the `Compare` class is irrelevant to the actual issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I removed some irrelevant details

Comment: @273K open is a priority_queue, I included the definition

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide [Start with this](https://godbolt.org/z/TY6rY8oK9).  Add code to what you see there until the issue you are mentioning shows up.  As a matter of fact, that is exactly what you should have done to whittle down the problem -- start off with nothing, add a few definitions, *and test*.  Once you see hard-coded, "I don't care if it's A* related or not" data passing the tests, then you take the code and apply it to the larger application.

Comment: @273K there was a typo, fixed it

Comment: @273K I don't think so, I think the condition is only true if open is not empty and the other check is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `std::set<std::pair<cost_t, Node *>>` to store key value pairs and then deleting and reinserting on key updates solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common error when working with `std::priority_queue`. Once you modify an element's key and reinsert it, the queue isn't aware of this change. This messes with the priority order. Unfortunately, the STL's `priority_queue` lacks a direct `decrease_key` operation. So, people often resort to the reinsertion technique to sidestep this limitation.

To get your implementation on track, there are a couple of things you might want to revise:

1. **Handling Duplicates**: I noticed you're leveraging the `closed` set to bypass nodes that have been dealt with, and that's good. But due to the reinsertion method, the `open` queue can end up housing multiple versions of the same node. It's a tricky situation because even if you process the node with the most accurate cost first, redundant copies remain in the queue.
2. **Comparator Tweaks**: It's essential for your comparator to differentiate between nodes having identical `fcost`. A handy trick to break this tie is by considering another attribute.

Here's what I'd suggest:

**1. Comparator Modification**

When nodes share the same `fcost`, you could use the heuristic value (`h` value) to set them apart. Typically, nodes with a smaller heuristic are given higher priority.

```cpp
class Compare {
public:
    bool operator() (BaseNode* a, BaseNode* b) {
        if (a->fcost == b->fcost) {
            return a->hValue > b->hValue; // I'm assuming there's an hValue in your node
        }
        return a->fcost > b->fcost;
    }

    bool operator() (const BaseNode& a, const BaseNode& b) {
        if (a.fcost == b.fcost) {
            return a.hValue > b.hValue;
        }
        return a.fcost > b.fcost;
    }
};
```

**2. Node Update Check**

Rather than directly throwing the node back into the queue, consider marking it as updated. Later on, when you're about to process a node, check if it has been updated. If so, pop and reinsert it. This could streamline things a bit.

```cpp
if (nextParent->getGCost() + edgeCost < child->getGCost()) {
    child->setGCost(nextParent->getGCost() + edgeCost);
    child->setFCost(child->getGCost() + (*h)(state));
    child->setBack(nextParent);
    child->updated = true;  // You'd need to add this attribute to your Node
}
```

When processing:

```cpp
Node *nextParent = open.top();
if (nextParent->updated) {
    open.pop();
    open.push(nextParent);
    continue;
}
```

Hope this helps with your problem. Happy coding!

Edit:

Alright so, after reading your comment, I’ve decided to add a little part more tailored to your problem. The issue with `std::priority_queue` is that it is not optimized for data structures that have frequent updates to nodes. In fact, there is no mechanism to re-evaluate the position of a modified item in the queue after reinsertion. **The issue with this is that the new insertion of the updated node doesn’t guarantee that it will be the top if other nodes with previously higher priorities are still in the queue.**

You can go with either two approaches:

1. **Utilize a different data structure**

As I said before, `std::priority_queue` is n’t a really good data structure for node updates. Therefore you could use alternatives such as `boost::heap::fibonacci_heap` or `boost::heap::d_ary_heap` as they support `increase` and `decrease` operations.

Though if you really insist with using `std::priority_queue`  you could try the next approach:

2. **Force Priority Updates with Complete Refresh:**

If you still intend on using `std::priority_queue` you can try and bruteforce the correct values by rebuilding the whole queue. This is very inefficient and can eventually slow down with a lot of node values. Here’s a snippet as an example:

```cpp
// Create a temporary container to hold nodes
std::vector<Node*> tempContainer;

while (!open.empty()) {
    tempContainer.push_back(open.top());
    open.pop();
}

// Re-insert nodes into the priority queue
for (Node* node : tempContainer) {
    open.push(node);
}
```

You could do this every time you refresh a node’s value but as I said and will repeat, **this method is inefficient** and can slow down with lots of node values, yet it guarantees correctness. Me personally, I’d try to use the alternatives I previously mentioned.

Hope this clears up.

Comment: I don't think this update check would resolve the problem of nodes which have a lower, but changed fcost not getting popped before nodes with higher fcost. Reinsertion should make it so that when a node is updated, the priority updates as well, but that doesn't seem to be happening, which was my original problem.

Comment: Edited my answer to add some additional insights to answer your comment.